# How increase the threshold for List View in App for SharePoint 2013 if count is more than the Threshold value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How increase the threshold for List View in App for SharePoint 2013 if count is more than the Threshold value.

If there is no way to do this, are there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the Threshold value for list in SharePoint Online.

To work around this issue, review the recommendations, techniques, and tips outlined in the "Ways to manage lists and libraries with many items" section of the "Manage lists and libraries with many items" guidance located at the following Microsoft website:

[Manage lists and libraries with many items](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Answer (score 0):

The subject and tagging are conflicting as tag is about Online but otherwise text speaks of 2013. As Hardik said, this is not possible in SharePoint Online.

In on-prem SharePoint 2013 the List View threshold can be increased on web application level from Central Admin. Navigate to Manage web applications, select the web application in question, under General Settings (from ribbon) select Resource Throttling.

Generally it is not recommended to increase these limits, they are there for a reason (SQL server can get database locked for large operations). But still the limit can be raised a bit for normal use. We're running some web apps with 10,000 as the cap.
For temporary situation I've tested up to 600,000 but that should be just for very brief and specific needs.